# Sections repeated in TOC when using \uncover in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am making a presentation in `beamer` and I am using `uncover<>{}` to make it a bit more interactive. The problem is that when I use it, I get a second entry in the `toc`.

[image]

Also the `themebars` on top seem to malfunction in the sense that they also add a second identical entry.

[image]

My code is

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\definecolor{charcoal}{RGB}{34,34,34}
%Packages
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}%Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\mode<presentation>

%Theme commands
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
% \setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}% Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=charcoal}
% 
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%Pages at the bottom right corner
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\title[\eng{Benchmarking} $^{nat}B(p,p)^{nat}B$]{\smallΈλεγχος Αξιοπιστίας Διαφορικών Ενεργών Διατομών Ελαστικής Σκέδασης Πρωτονίων σε Στόχο Φυσικού
Βορίου}
\author[Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος]{Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}
\institute[Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))]{Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Περιεχόμενα}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \section{Εισαγωγή}
 \subsection{Διαφορική Ενεργός Διατομή}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{(Διαφορική) Ενεργός Διατομή}: Πιθανότητα αλληλεπίδρασης ανά μονάδα επιφάνειας (ανά μονάδα στερεάς γωνίας)
  \item $\dfrac{d \sigma}{d \Omega} = \dfrac{Y}{N \left(Q\Omega\right)}\;,        
        \uncover<2->{\begin{array}{ll}
         Y : & \text{ανιχνευόμενων σωματιδίων}\\
         N : &\text{ Πάχος του στόχου}\\
         Q : & \text{προσπίπτοντων σωματιδίων στον στόχο}\\
         \Omega : & \text{ Στερεά γωνία}
        \end{array}}
        $
  \item \textbf{Μέτρηση} : Λεπτοί στόχοι(\eng{energy straggling})
  \item \textbf{Γιατί} : \begin{enumerate}
                          \item Βασική Έρευνα (Πυρηνικά Μοντέλα)
                          \item Εφαρμοσμένη Έρευνα (Τεχνολογία Ημιαγωγών)
                          \item Πολιτιστική Κληρονομιά-Τέχνη (Αρχαιότητες, Πίνακες)
                         \end{enumerate}

 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Also there are no circles on top. Any idea why are these malfunctions occuring and how can they be avoided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `beamer` sectioning commands should go *outside* of frames (as frame content may be processed multiple times):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
  Some content\\
  \uncover<2->{Some more content}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've minimised the example: the issue is quite general and not linked to Greek :-)